# How to install Cuda correctly on Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: nvidia, 15.10, cuda

*Please do not copy-paste from the Ubuntu wiki about installing the open-source driver.*

I need to use Cuda so I will need to get this driver working.

---

Here's the situation:

- The system works fine with the open source driver (but no Cuda).
- It also works fine with the proprietary driver (tested).
- It is the driver from the Cuda repo (suggested on Nvidia's website), that causes issues.

  - When using this driver, the display manager (SDDM or LightDM) will not start (even manually). From my limited memory of Nvidia driver hell, it is likely that there is some mismatch preventing OpenGL from being used or preventing X from starting.

Relevant system specs:

- Nvidia Quadro g86/NVS 290. It supports Cuda, so it's just a matter of finding out which driver/cuda package combo I need.
- I'm using kernel 4.2 (Standard fare).
- Nothing fancy installed, it's a fresh install.

Comment: Which is your nvidia card?

Comment: @dadexix86 Quadro G86 (NVS 290)

Comment: Your card [is not supported by the drivers 352](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/95159/en-us), you have to use the [drivers 340, that support it](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/95165/en-us).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it turns out that I had the wrong driver, AND it also turns out that Blender dropped support for cards this age :(. A lose lose situation.

Comment: @dadexix86 thanks! I did some further reading and found out that not only are you correct, but my card is useless for what I wanted it for anyway :(. Still have to replace it.